How to restore accidentally deleted tab
I have accidentally deleted tab from my Salesforce org, I cannot find it in recycle bin. Is there any way to restore custom object or visualforce tab?

No. Once you delete a component such a tab or Apex Class, it is gone forever. The few exceptions to this are objects and fields, which can be restored for a limited time. If you have a Sandbox or other backup, you can redeploy it from there, but you will still have to restore any related settings, such as profile access and apps.
